# How can I run a Spring REST service in the IntelliJ debugger (built via maven)

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am able to build the Sprint RESTful server and then run the server from the command line using:

java -jar rest-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

But how can I run it under the IntelliJ debugger? In IntelliJ in the Maven Projects window it includes Lifecycle choices of: package, site, & deploy but none of these if run under the debugger actually start the server.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html

Comment: Spring boot run plugin will add run lifecycle

Comment: Also you can configure from edit configuration

Comment: Just start the project from your IDE via Debugging ...go to that main class of your your spring boot application (The class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` on that you can run from IDE with Debugging...